# How can I start automatically start a tmux session on login?

Tags: login, tmux

I want to automatically start a new tmux session IF there are none available when I sudo to root.

e.g.

1. reboot PC
2. login as normal user via ssh
3. sudo -s (which would then automatically create a new tmux session)
4. I open another terminal/putty windows and login repeat 2 and 3 BUT this time, no session will be created as there's already one.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) makes it easy to enable and disable automatic tmux sessions on login. If you are willing to install and use [byobu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/byobu) [image: Install byobu] as an interface to tmux to address this need, it makes it extremely simple to do what you are asking. In a terminal, run

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
sudo byobu-enable
sudo -i
```

From now on, when the root user logs in via the console, SSH, or with `sudo -i`, byobu will attach to an existing tmux session or create a new one if one is not already running.

Note that I use `sudo -i` instead of `sudo -s`. The `-s` option only starts a shell, not a login shell. You should use `sudo -i` to emulate a full login, which also loads roots `~/.profile`, and this is where byobu will install itself when you run `byobu-enable`.

There are probably ways to do what you want with tmux alone, but byobu makes setting up and starting tmux automatically very simple.